# SQL getting the average count of diagnosis based on specialty

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables one for appointments and one for doctors.

I want to    select    the average number of patients for each specialty, which is stored in the doctors table. The appointments table has the patients' id the doctors' id and the diagnosis, if a patient has had a diagnosis.

I tried this, but doesn't work.

```
SELECT  AVG(patientAMKA)
  FROM appointments 
 WHERE diagnosis IS NOT NULL  
 GROUP 
    BY doctor.specialty
```

EDIT: I just want to clarify that patientAMKA is the id of the patient.
EDIT2: I specifically mean how many patients (with a diagnosis) exist for each speciaity, then take the average of those numbers.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What is `patientAMKA`? It seems like you should average a number probably a count, but I'm guessing that isn't what `patientAMKA` is.

Comment: There are a few different things you could mean by "the average number of patients for each speciality": (A) One number: find how many patients (with a diagnosis) exist for each speciaity, then take the average of those numbers. (B) A number per speciality: Within each speciality, find how many diagnoses each doctor has made, then find the averages of those. The way you worded the question sounds more like (A), but (B) seems a much more worthwhile question. And you might mean something else entirely!

Comment: A quick google suggests `patientAMKA` is the patient ID (like National Insurance Number (UK), or Social Security Number (US)). So averaging those IDs is definitely not what you want to do.

Comment: We didn't hear back from you @ΓιωργοςΜουρτιδης. If one of the answers below meets your needs, please mark it as accepted. If not, please let us know how they fail.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it would be something like:

```
SELECT d.specialty, COUNT(*)
FROM doctor d
INNER JOIN appointments a ON d.id = a.doctor_id
WHERE diagnosis IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY d.specialty
```

Comment: Pretty sure this can't be what the OP wants (though it's very unclear). I think this code calculates the average patient ID per speciality !?

Comment: @SteveLovell. I agree - I was confused by that part too. Seems like a COUNT of appointments makes more sense here, but this is how the OP has it, so I will let him/her comment if this is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT doc.specialty, AVG(app.patientAMKA)
FROM doctor doc
JOIN appointments app ON doc.doctorid = app.doctorid
WHERE app.diagnosis IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY doc.specialty
```

Comment: Pretty sure this can't be what the OP wants (though it's very unclear). I think this code calculates the average patient ID per speciality !?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarifications, I believe what you want is:

```
SELECT
    AVG(CountOfDiagnoses) as TheAverage
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        d.specialty,
        COUNT(1) as CountOfDiagnoses
    FROM
        appointments a
        JOIN doctor d ON
            d.doctor_id = a.doctor_id
    WHERE
        a.diagnosis IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        d.specialty
    ) Counts
```